Netgear Nighthawk X4S R7800 - can QoS de-prioritise specific device?
I have a single machine on my network which I use for any large internet uploads or downloads. Whenever a large transfer is in progress, internet speed for other devices on the LAN is badly affected. Is there any way of using QoS on my R7800 to deprioritise traffic from this machine, so that it does not cause problems for other LAN users when there is a large download/upload in progress?
There only seems to be a simple checkbox to switch QoS on or off on the router's QoS settings page - "Dynamic QoS: Automatic traffic prioritization by application and device"

See the
Nighthawk X4S AC2600 Smart WiFi Router User Manual.
Unfortunately, your router doesn't support priority rules.
It has an option for "Dynamic QoS" that supposedly will improve
congestion handling.
It has the ability to schedule blocks to websites by keywords and name,
see the section "Control Access to the Internet".
You can this way block some websites at given times of the day,
which is the most that you can do.

Ok many thanks for clarifying
